# page.params is undefined in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm new in using SvelteKit. I read the docs (I'm doing my best to follow along and follow what's there to make my website work).

In my `src > routes > posts > [postId].svelte`:

```
<script>
    // http://localhost:3000/posts/[postId]

    import PostDetails from '../../components/pages/PostDetails.svelte';
</script>

<PostDetails />
```

In my `src > components > pages > PostDetail.svelte`:

```
<script>
   import { page } from '$app/stores';

   console.log({ page });
   console.log('page.params', page.params);
</script>

<h1>Post Title</h1>
```

I want to get the `page.params.postId` but it doesn't work. So I've decided to log the value of `page` and `page.params` on the console:

[image]

As stated [in the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading-input-page), I was expecting to get `{ host, path, params, query }` from this `page` object. But I got nothing but a `subscribe` function. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`page` from `$app/stores` is a store, which means you need to `subscribe` to it to get the current value. That's because the value is not fixed but updates every time the page updates. To easily subscribe, to the store, prefix it with a `$` sign:

```html
<script>
   import { page } from '$app/stores';

   // manually (don't forget to unsubscribe in onDestroy to avoid memory leaks)
   page.subscribe(currentPage => console.log(currentPage));

   // easier
   console.log({ page: $page });
   console.log('page.params', $page.params);
</script>

<h1>Post Title</h1>
```

Docs on `$app/stores`: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores 
Docs on autosubscription with `$`: https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values